# After update button is clicked,than it does not go to php file written inside anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is the code Snippet :

```
echo "<td><a href=SalaryUpdateForm.php?id = " . $resultArr["EmployeeId"] . " Update  </a></td>";
```

Comment: You are already “in” a PHP block since you are using echo, so having `<?php` in there again of course makes no sense whatsoever. Go read up on the basics of the syntax ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Ok but now also it is not redirecting to the  link.

Comment: `button` can not be nested in `a`, that is invalid HTML. So remove that first. And then check the HTML output your PHP code generates, and see if that is what you expected it to be.

Comment: than instead of button i should use input tag ?

Comment: No, you should use a normal link if you want to link somewhere. If you need it to _look_ like a button, then you format it accordingly.

Comment: now Update is not visible .    here is the code:    echo "<td><a href='SalaryUpdateForm.php?id = ".$resultArr["EmployeeId"]." ?>'
                        Update..</a></td>";

Comment: `?>` still ends the PHP code at that point ...

Comment: Now also Update text is not visible . ? why ?

Comment: Help is required , Please

Comment: Then edit your question please, and add what your current code is.

Comment: i have edited my question ,Please consider

Comment: @Rajat , check my answer and let me know if you still fetch error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code , this will helpful to you.

```
 $id = $resultArr["EmployeeId"];
 echo "<td><a href='SalaryUpdateForm.php?id=$id'>Update..</a></td>";
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION IS:**

```
 echo "<td><a href='SalaryUpdateForm.php?id=$resultArr[EmployeeId]'>Update..</a></td>";
```

When you use `""` then you can easily use php variables without concatinate.

Comment: still not going to the file given in link. It is redirecting to another file

Comment: in which file it is redirect you ?